# surefire command line options ignored

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

command line option name appears to be ignored in the following:

```
mvn surefire-report:failsafe-report-only -Dtitle=IntegrationTest 
-DoutputName=IntTest
```

The option, outputName, always works regardless of order of the options but the other is ignored.

Is the options names incorrect? How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The options must be entered by their user property names

```
surefire-report:failsafe-report-only -Dfailsafe.report.title=IntegrationTest   -DoutputName=IntTest
```

I hope this helps someone.